# Copy paste into Nano from external source while keeping same indentation

Tags: windows, ubuntu, copy-paste, nano

Im trying to copy-paste a python script from my notepad in Windows into the Nano editor in Ubuntu.
But when i do this the Indentation gets messed up and Nano puts many lines into the same line

In python my code looks like this

```
Import xyz 
Import blabla
```

In Nano it will look like this

```
Import xyz Import blabla.
```

So Nano puts many lines into one line. How can i copy-paste while keeping the same formatting so that i can run my script?

Comment: What line endings are you using in Notepad?

Comment: Are you using WSL? What terminal/console are you accessing it with?

Comment: im using Amazon AWS ERC2 instance from the browser. Im quite inexperienced with programming. I don't know how i can acces line ending settings in notepad. I tried copy-pasting from notepad into word/google docs/other notepad first, but i keep getting same result when pasting the text into Nano in ubuntu server

Comment: Do you mean EC2?

Comment: I have a hunch that EC2 is using `hterm` as a terminal app. [This thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-hterm/c/7zA9_Gwxzts/m/Cj8bK8S1BAAJ) seems to support that. That might help you find a solution, though in my experience, `hterm` is pretty buggy regarding lines in all sorts of different ways.

Comment: As a workaround, could you use SSH instead?

Comment: Thx! that seems like a smart idea!

Comment: worked! Ty so much! didnt know it was possible to acces the AWS server like this. Works much smoother

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. In your code source: copy to clipboard
2. In the BASh terminal `cat > foo.php`  (where foo.php is your intended filename)
3. See the terminal awaiting input of text
4. Paste to the terminal(in my terminal, `Ctl-Shift-V`)
5. Open the new file in nano: `nano foo.php`